# Is there a way to make 3 divs side by side and responsive with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need a way to put 3 divs side by side. The Left side one will have text, the middle one will have image and the right side will have text. I also want it responsive to it could be mobile friendly. Is there a way to do that? Whenever I try using flexbox or css-grid, it keeps becoming 2 divs or I can't put any images. I also got a `flexbox is not defined` error message. Can you help me?

Here is the code I tried

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
        <head> 
            
            <!-- CSS property to place div 
                side by side -->
            <style> 
                #leftbox { 
                    float:left; 
                    background:Red; 
                    width:25%; 
                    height:280px; 
                } 
                #middlebox{ 
                    float:left; 
                    background:Green; 
                    width:50%; 
                    height:280px; 
                } 
                #rightbox{ 
                    float:right; 
                    background:blue; 
                    width:25%; 
                    height:280px; 
                } 
                h1{ 
                    color:green; 
                    text-align:center; 
                } 
            </style> 
        </head> 
        
        <body> 
            <div id = "boxes"> 
                
                <div id = "leftbox"> 
                    Text
                </div> 
                
                <div id = "middlebox"> 
                    I can't put an image here.
                </div> 
                
                <div id = "rightbox"> 
                    Box 3
            </div> 
            </div> 
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define col-count that one div will take (see code below).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">first</div>
    <div class="col-4">second</div>
    <div class="col-4">third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="col">This div takes up 1/3 of the available width on a desktop</div>
      <div class="col">This div takes up 1/3 of the available width on a desktop</div>
      <div class="col">This div takes up 1/3 of the available width on a desktop</div>
    </div>
```